# how to sort map based on keys

Tags: sorting, clojure

I have the following map:

```
MyVals {12 -3, 24 -9, 36 -777, 48 -3037, 180 0, 360 0, 240 0, 120 0, 0 0, 144 0, 3 0, 6 -1, 9 -1, 108 0, 60 0, 72 0, 84 0, 96 0}
```

I am removing zero values then I need to sort it by the key

```
MyValsZeroRemoved(apply merge (for [[k v] MyVals :when (not (= 0 v))] {k v}))
```

Which returns:

```
MyValsZeroRemoved {9 -1, 6 -1, 48 -3037, 36 -777, 24 -9, 12 -3}
```

Then I sort it:

```
MyValsZeroRemovedSorted(sort MyValsZeroRemoved)
```

but that results in

```
([12 -3] [24 -9] [36 -777] [48 -3037] [6 -1] [9 -1])
```

How do I sort the map to get the desired output as below:

```
([6 -1] [9 -1] [12 -3] [24 -9] [36 -777] [48 -3037])
```

Comment: Show us how you ran `sort` to get output like that.

Comment: yeah sort does the right thing `(sort {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23}) => ([0 -1] [3 3] [6 5] [9 7] [12 23] [24 3203] [36 4670])`

Comment: see original post for details

Comment: Apologies guys just realised I have the key as a string somehow - converting to int solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you get that sort order is if you did

```
(sort-by (comp str first) {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23})
;=>  ([0 -1] [12 23] [24 3203] [3 3] [36 4670] [6 5] [9 7])
```

That will sort them as strings. If you need to sort a map by key literals then regular sort works

```
(sort {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23})
;=>  ([0 -1] [3 3] [6 5] [9 7] [12 23] [24 3203] [36 4670])
```

If you need to sort by the value or if you need to convert the key or value then you should use sort-by and a function to extract the value to perform the conversion.

```
(sort-by second {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23})
;=>  ([0 -1] [3 3] [6 5] [9 7] [12 23] [24 3203] [36 4670])
```

Comment: While it yields the same result, I think what @redhands is looking for is `(sort-by first {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23})` because they'd like to sort by the key.

Comment: That would be sorting by value only. In this case, it doesn't matter because the values and the keys, if sorted Least -> greatest or greatest -> least, end up with the same result. However, I'm curious how @redhands wishes to sort this map. Does he want the keys sorted or the values...possibly both?

Comment: If the input is a map, this is identical behavior to the standard `sort` ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` function will give the output you want.

```
user> (sort {9 7, 6 5, 3 3, 0 -1, 36 4670, 24 3203, 12 23})
([0 -1] [3 3] [6 5] [9 7] [12 23] [24 3203] [36 4670])
```